# How to keep an array member count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using nodeJS + Express + Mongoose + mongoDB

Here's my mongoDB User Schema:

```
{
  friends: [ObjectId]
  friends_count: Number
}
```

Whenever user adds a friend, a friendId will be pushed into friends array, and friends_count will be increased by 1.

Maybe there are a lot of actions will change the friends array, and maybe I will forgot to increase the friends_count. So I want to make sure that friends_count always equal to friends.length

Is there a good way or framework to make sure all of that?

P.S
I know how to update friends_count. What I mean is what if I forgot to?
Is there a way to automatically keep these two attributes sync?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator as a "query" argument to [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) and the [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to apply when that "friend" did not exist within the array as you [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) the new member:

```js
User.update(
    { "_id": docId, "friends": { "$ne": friendId } },
    {
        "$push": { "friends": friendId },
        "$inc": { "friends_count": 1 }
    },
    function(err,numberAffected) {

    }     
)
```

Or to "remove" a friend from the list, do the reverse case with [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/):

```js
User.update(
    { "_id": docId, "friends": friendId },
    {
        "$pull": { "friends": friendId },
        "$inc": { "friends_count": -1 }
    },
    function(err,numberAffected) {

    }     
)
```

That way your `friends_count` stays in sync with the number of array elements present.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i know how to update friends_count. What i mean is what if i forgot to? is there a way to automatically keep these two attributes sync?

Comment: @kilik52 That is what is happening. MongoDB itself is "schemaless" and does not track such things. If you contruct all of your operations to add and remove from the array like this, then they are safe and atomic and **always** keep track of the correct count. You can add hooks to a mongoose schema, but that requires a `.find()` and `.save()` pattern that is netiher "safe" or "scalable".

Comment: in theory they will **always** sync. but i found in my db, occasionally they were unsync. and i cannot found out why....

Comment: @kilik52 Because you did something wrong, and you likely were not following this pattern as demonstrated here. Again, "schemaless"! MongoDB does not do anything at all to enforce this and **cannot** by design. You can bulk update your data to correct it, and make sure that your continuing updates follow the practice **here**. But aside from periodically doing an "check" and "update", there is no such way of "enforcing" that your numeric field **always** reflects the array length. That is what "schemaless" means. What else could you expect?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to update `friends_count` in both add and remove functions. For example:

```
User.findById(userId, function (err, user) {
    if (user) {
        user.friends.push(friendId);
        user.friends_count++;
        user.save();
    }
});
```

FYI, I don't think it is necessary to add friends_count while you can get total numbers of friends by `friends.length`.

Comment: sometime only friends_count is needed. i can select "friends_count" only. will it cause any performance issue if i retrieve a large friends array from DB?